# RavenDB DocumentId with whitespaces

Tags: ravendb

Is it recommended to have white spaces in a documentId when using ravenDB: for example Job\E15E83C2-7C00-491D-8EAE-DD8B4ED6DA77\file one.pdf

Can anyone think of any problems?

Comment: This is your ID? Without knowing about ravenDB I recommend shorter IDs with limited length. Can't say anything about the space but I wouldn't - it's normally not a problem but not good style

Answer (score 0):

Spaces are supported, but it is easier to avoid them if you can.